# Oracle ASM dgname name

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

One of our customer has issue with renamedg followings are the details, I am suspecting the issue may be with `newdgname=_FACASM` newdgname starting with '_'. But could find any reference to support the same

Can we have dgname starting with '_' ?

```
renamedg operation: dgname=RXIODATA01 newdgname=_FACASM asm_diskstring=/dev/test-data-514f0c57dbe0008d*
Executing phase 1
Discovering the group
KFNDG-00407: file not found; arguments: [/dev/test-data-514f0c57dbe0008d*]
```

Thanks

Comment: did you check this already: http://oracleabout.blogspot.de/search/label/KFNDG-00407%3A%20file%20not%20found

Comment: Sorry I could not find  relevant answer in above link.